# RedBean (ORM) Get Bean with his relations like other Bean

Tags: redbean

I'm storing a product Bean, by this way:

```
$product = R::dispense( 'product' ); 
$product->name = $_POST['name']; 
$product->description = $_POST['description']; 
$product->price = $_POST['price']; 
$product->category = $_POST['category']; 
R::store( $product );
```

How can I indicate that the category's attribute is an id reference (or 
FK) to the category Bean? I want get the category Bean like this way:

```
$products = R::find( 'product' ); 
foreach( $products as $product ) 
   $productCategory = $product->category->name;
```

Comment: TIP! Instead of setting each property individually you can automatically fill a bean with a $_POST array using:

    $bean->import($_GET);
    $bean->import($_POST, "name,year"); //only these fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is this **IF** you don't have the database table already configured:

```
$product = R::dispense( 'product' ); 
$product->name = $_POST['name']; 
$product->description = $_POST['description']; 
$product->price = $_POST['price']; 
$product->category = R::load('category',$_POST['category']); 
R::store( $product );
```

**BUT** I believe if your database has a foreign index assigned for category and it points to the category table, then you can do what you did above.  So on your `product` table, have a column `category_id` and make it a foreign index to `category.id` and it *should* work.  I can test it later and give you a more definitive answer, but this is just going off of what I know offhand.

Comment: Thanks! when a set the category attributte like a Beans, automatically create de column an FKeys! it's brilliant :D